# How to reuse last answer on Ti-84?

Tags: calculator

Someone changed the settings on my Ti-84 calculator. Before it acted as follows. You compute something, say $8+9$, it outputs $17$. Then pressing '10', '+', and then '2nd' and '(-)' simultaneously had the effect of computing $10+ans$ where $ans$ is the last outputted number. That is, the final output would be $10+17=27$.

But now pressing '2nd' and '(-)' (the key with ANS labeled above it) simultaneously doesn't do anything.

How can I get back to the old setting?

Comment: You might be in a program…try pressing the ON key to see if it breaks out.

Comment: Also, try pressing the buttons in succession; not at the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons this could be happening:

- You are in a program as suggested  in the comments. Press on or exit the program another way.
- One or both of the keys are not functioning correctly. To test this, press `2nd`and see if the little arrow pops up in the corner. If it does, this is good. Alto test your - key by seeing if it will type -.
- Your pressing is off. Make sure you are pressing the 2nd key first. It shouldn't matter if you continue holding it or not.
- There is something wrong with your calculator's internal workings. You might try re-installing the OS and/or changing the batteries.

I hope one of these works for you.